# Many to many relation not loading

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to define a m:n relationship between Injury and Tag but tags are not loaded.

My entites are defined as the following

```
@Entity
data class Injury(
    val description: String,
    val occurredAt: LocalDateTime,
    val loggedAt: LocalDateTime,
    override val updated: LocalDateTime,
    val created: LocalDateTime,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: Long
) : UpdatableEntity

@Entity
data class Tag(
    val name: String,
    override val updated: LocalDateTime,
    val created: LocalDateTime,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: Long
) : UpdatableEntity

@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["injuryId", "tagId"],
    indices = [Index("injuryId"), Index("tagId")],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Injury::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["injuryId"]
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Tag::class,
            childColumns = ["tagId"],
            parentColumns = ["id"]
        )
    ]
)
data class InjuryTagsCrossReference(
    val injuryId: Long,
    val tagId: Long
)

data class InjuryWithTags(
    @Embedded
    val injury: Injury,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(InjuryTagsCrossReference::class, parentColumn = "tagId", entityColumn = "injuryId")
    )
    val tags: List<Tag>
)
```

My dao is defined as the following

```
@Dao
interface InjuryDao : UpdatableDao<Injury> {
    @Transaction
    @Query("select * from Injury order by updated desc")
    fun findAll(): LiveData<List<InjuryWithTags>>
}
```

As the title indicates the `tags` property of `InjuryWithTags` isn't populated and no error is shown. Any clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try to replace columns' order in Junction:

```
data class InjuryWithTags(
@Embedded
val injury: Injury,
@Relation(
    parentColumn = "id",
    entityColumn = "id",

    associateBy = Junction(InjuryTagsCrossReference::class, 
    parentColumn = "injuryId", entityColumn = "tagId") // <= try change here
)
val tags: List<Tag>
```

)